# How do you make an app on MySQL that queries the logs from SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logging

I wanted to make an app with MySQL that queries logs, because one of the fields I track is a "$ balance", and I want to be able to show the user all transactions (filterable) that have happened in the past X days or months, maybe even with a comment. However, I don't want to use more space then necessary.

How would I query MySQL logs from SQL, or is there no way to do that? Can I add a comment to a transaction to store in the logs?

Or would I have to make a separate table of transaction logs since a certain date?

Comment: MySQL logs are text files, they're not SQL tables. You can't query them from MySQL itself.

Comment: Oh, that's disappointing. I suppose binary logs are similar.

Comment: @id01 . . . You should be keeping a `transactions` table in your database.  Providing such history is not the purpose of log files.  You just need the correct data model.